# JSON Schema - field named "type"

Tags: jsonschema

I have an **existing JSON data feed** between multiple systems which I **do not control** and **cannot change**. I have been tasked with writing a schema for this feed. The **existing JSON** looks in part like this:

```
 "ids": [
            { "type": "payroll", "value": "011808237" },
            { "type": "geid",  "value":  "31826" }
           ]
```

When I try to define a JSON schema for this, I wind up with a scrap of schema that looks like this:

```
"properties": {
    "type": {                   <====================== PROBLEM!!!!
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [ "payroll", "geid" ]
    },
    "value": {
        "type": [ "string", "null" ],
        "pattern": "^[0-9]*$"
    }
}
```

As you might guess, when the JSON validator hits that "type" on the line marked "PROBLEM!!!" it gets upset and throws an error about how type needs to be a string or array.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproduceable example please? There might be a problem with your setup or the way you're using a library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a bug in the particular implementation you're using, and should be reported as such. It should be able to handle properties-that-look-like-keywords just fine. In fact, the metaschema (the schema to valid schemas) uses "type" in exactly this way, along with all the other keywords too: e.g. http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema

I wonder if it is not making use of the official test suite (https://github.com/json-schema-org/JSON-Schema-Test-Suite)?

You didn't indicate what implementation you're using, or what language, but perhaps you can find an alternative one here: https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validators

Comment: Well that's a disappointing answer, but I'm marking it as accepted answer. Leaving my work-around in case someone else is stuck using a bad implementation, though.

Answer (score 0):

I found at least a work-around if not a proper solution. Instead of `"type"` inside `"properties"`, use `"^type$"` inside `"patternProperties"`. I.e.

```
"patternProperties": {
    "^type$": {
        "type": "string"
    }
}
```

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a great way to make `"^type$"` a required property. I've settled for listing all the other properties as `"required"` and setting the min and max property counts to the number that should be there.

Comment: You should be able to say `"required": ["type"]` alongside the "patternProperties" -- that is, "required" doesn't depend on the existence of "properties". Sounds like this implementation has *lots* of bugs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was throwing up on "type" in "required" as well. I'm using https://github.com/neilpa/yajsv which is linked from the "implementations" page but I picked it mostly because it was self-contained and I could easily download it and use it right away on my Windows system.

These schemas are ultimately going to be used in a system - that is owned by another company - running in AWS, and they haven't even implemented the validation code yet.